# Randomly SELECTing rows based on certain criteria

Tags: python, random

I'm building a media player for the office, and so far so good but I want to add a voting system (kinda like Pandora thumbs up/thumbs down)

To build the playlist, I am currently using the following code, which pulls 100 random tracks that haven't been played recently (we make sure all tracks have around the same play count), and then ensures we don't hear the same artist within 10 songs and builds a playlist of 50 songs.

```
max_value = Items.select(fn.Max(Items.count_play)).scalar()

    query = (Items
             .select()
             .where(Items.count_play < max_value, Items.count_skip_vote < 5)
             .order_by(fn.Rand()).limit(100))


    if query.count < 1:
            max_value = max_value - 1
            query = (Items
             .select()
             .where(Items.count_play < max_value, Items.count_skip_vote < 5)
             .order_by(fn.Rand()).limit(100))


    artistList = []
    playList = []
    for item in query:
            if len(playList) is 50:
                    break

            if item.artist not in artistList:
                    playList.append(item.path)

            if len(artistList) < 10:
                    artistList.append(item.artist)
            else:
                    artistList.pop(0)
                    artistList.append(item.artist)

    for path in playList:
            client.add(path.replace("/music/Library/",""))
```

I'm trying to work out the best way to use the up/down votes.
I want to see less with downvotes and more with upvotes.

I'm not after direct code because I'm pretty OK with python, it's more of the logic that I can't quite nut out (that being said, if you feel the need to improve my code, I won't stop you :) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially give each track a weight w, e.g. 10 - a vote up increases this, down reduces it (but never to 0). Then when deciding which track to play next:
Calculate the total of all the weights, generate a random number between 0 and this total, and step through the tracks from 0-49 adding up their w until you exceed the random number. play that track.

The exact weighting algorithm (e.g. how much an upvote/downvote changes w) will of course affect how often tracks (re)appear. Wasn't it Apple who had to change the 'random' shuffle of their early iPod because it could randomly play the same track twice (or close enough together for a user to notice) so they had to make it less random, which I presume means also changing the weighting by how recently the track was played - in that case the time since last play would also be taken into account at the time of choosing the next track. Make sure you cover the end cases where everyone downvotes 49 (or all 50 if they want silence) of the tracks. Or maybe that's what you want...